# iPhone How to make layer contet image grayscale?

Tags: iphone, animation, calayer, grayscale

I have layer, that has multiple sublayers containing images. I want to make all these images grayscale. Is there a way this can be done with some animation?

Like for example adding setting opacity property to 0.8 will make all content in layer a little transparent.